# How to format branching statements (while/if-else) in UML use case descriptions?

Tags: uml, use-case

How are branching statements supposed to be written in UML use case descriptions? Here is the situation I am modelling -

An employee has to swipe a card through a card reader to clock into work. The system emits a sound signifying a read success or failure. If the read fails three times the user is given the option of entering their details manually into a PC.

Here is the use case description I have made, it seems very awkward and unclear with all the if/elses. Is this the way use case descriptions are supposed to be written or is there a better method?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **UML specification does not specify any way** to show branching within a use case specification. However, **modelers have come up with a few suggestions** one of which is very similar to what you already have. In the book [UML 2 and The Unified Process](http://www.amazon.ca/UML-Unified-Process-Practical-Object-Oriented/dp/0321321278) (page 82) one such approach is introduced:

"Use the keywords 'If' and 'Else' to indicate a branch within a flow. You can clearly indicate the body of an 'If' statement by careful use of indentation and numbering."

```
n. If condition
    n.1 Do something
    n.2 Do something else
    ...
n+1. Else
    n+1.1 Do something
    n+1.2 Do something else
    ...
n+2. ...
```

Note that you may want to **drop the 'end if' phrases**. The book also introduces other keywords such as 'For' and 'While'.

From my personal experience however; flows of complicated use cases will not be read by anyone when they are expressed in text. The best approach I have seen in the industry is to **use activity diagrams** to show main flow of use cases. This is to have a use case specification with all the other parts (preconditions, post-conditions, name, description, primary and secondary actors and ...) but leave the flow part empty and refer to an activity diagram as completely explained by @javier. I would however mix the two diagrams and separate the user and system steps by activity partition (swim-lanes).

Sequence diagram is definitely not an option.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best would be to create a UML usecase and describe it with a sequence diagram...

Answer (score 0):

Use Case diagram is not intended to represent information you want. In your case I would use sequence diagram (and it looks like you already have swimlines ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you write the behavior of your use case as text, yes. Otherwise you could model it via an Activity Diagram with **send and receive actions** describing the interactions between user and system.

[image: Activity diagram]

I wouldn't choose a sequence diagram because it would look as "awkward" as the natural language description (due to nesting of *alternatives* and *loops*), but it is another option, as it was stated in the other answers.

Comment: +1 Explained a bit more in my answer but referred to yours which is the right approach.

Comment: maybe i'm nit-picking - but isn't there a syntax error in the right activity diagram? There's a fork node implying that both succes tone and failure tone happens in parallel? Should be a decision node...

Answer (score -1):

Use cases UML don't use if/then/else statements. Use cases use Alternate flows:

Main flow

N action a

N+1 result a

N+2 action a1

Alternate flow

N action a

N+1 result b

N+2 action a2

This is the Use case specification of

If result of action a is result a then do a1

else if result of action a is result b then do a2

end if